# Memory leak in Python extension when array is created with PyArray_SimpleNewFromData() and returned

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, memory-leaks

I wrote a simple Python extension module to simulate a 3-bit analog-to-digital converter. It is supposed to accept a floating-point array as its input to return the same size array of output. The output actually consists of quantized input numbers. Here is my (simplified) module:

```
static PyObject *adc3(PyObject *self, PyObject *args) {
  PyArrayObject *inArray = NULL, *outArray = NULL;
  double *pinp = NULL, *pout = NULL;
  npy_intp nelem;
  int dims[1], i, j;

  /* Get arguments:  */
  if (!PyArg_ParseTuple(args, "O:adc3", &inArray))
    return NULL;

  nelem = PyArray_DIM(inArray,0); /* size of the input array */
  pout = (double *) malloc(nelem*sizeof(double));
  pinp = (double *) PyArray_DATA(inArray);

  /*   ADC action   */
  for (i = 0; i < nelem; i++) {
    if (pinp[i] >= -0.5) {
    if      (pinp[i] < 0.5)   pout[i] = 0;
    else if (pinp[i] < 1.5)   pout[i] = 1;
    else if (pinp[i] < 2.5)   pout[i] = 2;
    else if (pinp[i] < 3.5)   pout[i] = 3;
    else                      pout[i] = 4;
    }
    else {
    if      (pinp[i] >= -1.5) pout[i] = -1;
    else if (pinp[i] >= -2.5) pout[i] = -2;
    else if (pinp[i] >= -3.5) pout[i] = -3;
    else                      pout[i] = -4;
    }
  }

  dims[0] = nelem;

  outArray = (PyArrayObject *)
               PyArray_SimpleNewFromData(1, dims, NPY_DOUBLE, pout);
  //Py_INCREF(outArray);

  return PyArray_Return(outArray); 
} 

/* ==== methods table ====================== */
static PyMethodDef mwa_methods[] = {
  {"adc", adc, METH_VARARGS, "n-bit Analog-to-Digital Converter (ADC)"},
  {NULL, NULL, 0, NULL}
};

/* ==== Initialize ====================== */
PyMODINIT_FUNC initmwa()  {
    Py_InitModule("mwa", mwa_methods);
    import_array();  // for NumPy
}
```

I expected that if reference counts were processed correctly, the Python garbage collection would (frequently enough) release the memory used by the output array if it has the same name and is used repeatedly. So I tested it on some dummy (but voluminous) data with this code:

```
for i in xrange(200): 
    a = rand(1000000)
    b = mwa.adc3(a)
    print i
```

Here the array named "b" is reused many times and its memory, borrowed by adc3() from the heap, is expected to be returned to the system. I used the gnome-system-monitor to check. Contrary to my expectations, the memory owned by python grew rapidly and could only be released by quitting the program (I use IPython).
For comparison, I tried the same procedure with the standard NumPy functions, zeros() and copy():

```
for i in xrange(1000): 
    a = np.zeros(10000000)
    b = np.copy(a)
    print i
```

As you can see, the latter code does not make any memory build-up. 
I read many texts in the standard documentation and on the web, tried to use Py_INCREF(outArray) and not to use it. All in vain: the problem persisted.

However, I found the solution in http://wiki.scipy.org/Cookbook/C_Extensions/NumPy_arrays.
The author provides an extension program  matsq() that creates an array and returns it. When I tried to use the calls suggested by the author:

```
outArray = (PyArrayObject *) PyArray_FromDims(nd,dims,NPY_DOUBLE);
pout = (double *) outArray->data;
```

instead of my

```
pout = (double *) malloc(nelem*sizeof(double));
outArray = (PyArrayObject *)
            PyArray_SimpleNewFromData(1, dims, NPY_DOUBLE, pout);
/* no matter with or without Py_INCREF(outArray)) */
```

the memory leak gone! The program works properly now.

A question: can anybody explain why PyArray_SimpleNewFromData() does not provide the correct reference counting, while PyArray_FromDims() does?

Thank you very much.

ADDITION. I probably exceeded the room/time in comments, so I add to my comment to Alex here.
I tried to set the OWNDATA flag this way:

```
outArray->flags |= OWNDATA;
```

but I got "error: ‘OWNDATA’ undeclared".
The rest is in the comment. Thank you in advance.

---

SOLVED: The correct setting of the flag is

```
outArray->flags |= NPY_ARRAY_OWNDATA;
```

Now it works.

Alex, sorry.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The problem is **not** with `PyArray_SimpleNewFromData` which produces a properly refcounted `PyObject*`.  Rather, it's with your `malloc`, assigned to `pout` then **never** `free`d.

As the docs at http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/c-info.how-to-extend.html clearly state, documenting `PyArray_SimpleNewFromData`:

> the `ndarray` will not own its data. When this `ndarray` is
>   deallocated, the pointer will **not** be freed.
>   ...
>   If you want the
>   memory to be freed as soon as the `ndarray` is deallocated then simply
>   set the `OWNDATA` flag on the returned `ndarray`.

(my emphasis on the **not**).  IOW, you're observing exactly the "will not be freed" behavior so clearly documented, and are not taking the step specifically recommended should you want to avoid said behavior.

Comment: Thank you, Alex. Your answer helped me to better understand the phrases from documentation you quoted. Of course, I read it before, and I could not understand what it can mean - "simply set the OWNDATA flag on the returned ndarray". If you know, please, tell. The parameter "requirements" - the combination of flags - is not present among the parameters of neither PyArray_SimpleNewFromData() nor PyArray_Return(). I tried to set it this way: The doc page you referred to has section "Array flags".

Comment: The doc page you referred to has section "Array flags". It says "There are 6 (binary) flags ... defined in arrayobject.h", but it is simply not the case. Surely, they promise "Python exposes a nice attribute- based interface ... for getting (and, if appropriate, setting) these flags", but do not provide any concrete information :). How do I "simply set" OWNDATA flag? Thank you.

Comment: `PyArray_ENABLEFLAGS(outArray, NPY_ARRAY_OWNDATA);` is the canonical way, but I guess your way (in your Q's edit) works too (in this release -- I'd use the documented way, just for future proofing, but then maybe I'm just a stickler for docs:-).  So can I have an accept now?-)

Comment: I agree, it is always better to use documented ways. "can I have an accept now?" - yes. I do not know what it is, I guess you are asking for closing the discussion as Moderator?

Comment: @Benkevitch, no, I was just asking you, as the original question, to accept this answer (by clicking on the checkmark sign just to the left of the answer, it will turn green).

Comment: It'd seem the current documentation (1.25) does not longer explain all this. Does it?