# Why does scipy.optimize.fmin_l_bfgs_b() memory usage increase with iterations?

Tags: python, scipy

I have been using `scipy.optimize.fmin_l_bfgs_b()` to minimize functions for a while now, but recently I ran into a behavior I have not noticed before. While optimizing some new function, memory usage keeps increasing as more iterations are executed. For example, by the 1500th iteration memory usage has increased x100 and in some cases I have to stop the optimization before running out of memory. For reference, I have run previously run `scipy.optimize.fmin_l_bfgs_b()` to optimize other functions and never saw an increase in memory usage.

From how I understand this function works, it should be performing a similar type of calculation at each iteration, so I don't understand why the memory usage would increase.

**Is this behavior expected, or is this probably some kind of memory leak** (either in `fmin_l_bfgs_b` or in the function I supply)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If memory is not deallocated in the minimization function, each call to the function will increase the memory allocation of your program. Most Python objects will properly deallocate.

I had this issue with an array that was returned from a C extension module where the module was responsible for allocating the memory but did not properly return it. Rewriting the module to correctly release memory solved the issue, the solution had been discussed here:

[Memory leak in Python extension when array is created with PyArray_SimpleNewFromData() and returned](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27912483/memory-leak-in-python-extension-when-array-is-created-with-pyarray-simplenewfrom)

Comment: I indeed found that it is a memory leak caused by my implementation of an extension of `numpy.ndarray`.